# HTML table hidden rows by comparing the current row with the previous row

Tags: php, html, css

Please help me, with how I can solve this
I have a project that looks like this table

[image]

and this is my code,

```
<table class = "table table-striped table-hover">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>No</th>
        <th>Student</th>
        <th>Course</th>
        <th>Grade</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <?php $no = 1; foreach($students as $student): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?=$no++?></td>
        <td><?=h($student->name)?></td>
        <td><?=h($student->course->name)?></td>
        <td><?=h($student->grade->result)?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</tbody>
```

What I want is, How I can make the table looks like this
[image]

Any references to solve this, I try using CSS to hide any element with the same value, but it doesn’t work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your table, We can record the previous student name and achieved the desired output.

```html
<table class="table table-striped table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>No</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Course</th>
      <th>Grade</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php
    $no = 1;
    $prevName = "";
    foreach ($students as $student) {
        $name = h($student->name);
        $course = h($student->course->name);
        $grade = h($student->grade->result);
        if ($name !== $prevName) { ?>
        <tr>
          <td><?= $no++ ?></td>
          <td><?= $name ?></td>
          <td><?= $course ?></td>
          <td><?= $grade ?></td>
        </tr>
      <?php } else { ?>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td><?= $course ?></td>
          <td><?= $grade ?></td>
        </tr>
      <?php }
        $prevName = $name;
    }
    ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Hope this will help you.